# dyld symbol not found DictionaryGenerator (IOS Xcode6 Beta4)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dyld

I having below log error after compile with latest Xcode6 Beta4 version. However there is not problem with Xcode6 Beta3. I have not idea on what the error message is about. I'm new to xcode. Please assist.

```
    dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdVSs19DictionaryGenerator
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/512B4D3F-F81E-42EF-9FD9-D808B066A833/*
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/512B4D3F-F81E-42EF-9FD9-D808B066A833/IRApp.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/512B4D3F-F81E-42EF-9FD9-D808B066A833/*
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from Apple's [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1008628#1008628):

> 1. Delete derived Data (Window/Organizer)
> 2. Clean (Cmd+Shift+K)
> 3. Re-run on device, after all the indexing and such was finished (dispayed at the top of xcode)

It seems like there have been a few errors similar to this floating around since the new beta was released. Although the error messages aren't exactly the same, they seem to have the same answer. I've personally run into this with a 3rd error related to ranges, and this was the solution in that case as well.

Comment: Thanks alots. The error has gone after delete derived data from window > organizer

Comment: I was getting a similar error (dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPV12CoreGraphics7CGFloatSs16SignedNumberType) and this worked perfectly!