# XCode 6 Beta 4 error - "An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Just updated from Xcode 6 Beta 3 to Beta 4 and everything seems to build fine but when the simulator tries to start up I get:

```
An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)
```

It was building fine on Beta 3 so I'm assuming this might be a Beta 4 bug but thought I'd throw this out there just to make sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't ask a question just to throw it out for ideas...

Comment: Do you have any simulators that don't belong to beta 4 open? Either from an earlier beta, or Xcode 5?

Comment: idea: it is still _beta_.

Answer (score 2):

I quit both Xcode and the simulator and then restarted. These steps solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues as well when I first updated. I did not get the same error as you. However, I was able to get things working by deleting my Pods (the project uses Cocoapods) and reinstalling them. I also quit and restarted Xcode as well as the Simulator. I'd also try restarting your computer. Good luck.

Comment: Also, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883053/dyld-symbol-not-found-dictionarygenerator-ios-xcode6-beta4

Comment: I seemed to get it working by following the steps from the answer I posted below.  Thanks for your comments tho.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to get this working again in Beta 4 by following instructions from the following question:

[Error opening iOS Simulator with iOS 8 beta version: "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim)

I had to reset a few times and had to do some of the steps multiple times, but my program now builds and runs on the simulator.